# Silent Notifications Won't Send In TestFlight

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My app relies heavily on silent notifications to send data to the user. This feature works fine in development but when I test with TestFlight it doesn't work. I read that is a possible bug in some iOS versions but I'm not running any of them. I'm using parse to send the push notifications and it says that the notifications are sent but it's not executing any of the code it `didReceiveRemoteNotification` Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
        "content-available" : 1,
        "sound" : "",
        "time" : alarmTimeDate,
    },
    push_time: alarmTime
}, { }).then(function() {
    response.success("Push was sent successfully.")
}, function(error) {
    response.error("Push failed to send with error: "
+ error.message);
});
},

error: function(user, error) { // error is an instance of Parse.Error. } });

 });
```

Comment: What code are you using to send them?

Comment: Is the application in a background or foreground state when the notification is received? (i.e. you haven't swiped up on it)

Comment: I have true the background and the foreground both aren't working it seems didReceiveRemoteNotification is not being called.

Comment: Please post your didReceiveRemoteNotification method. Eg, are you using the fetchCompletion one? Also, didReceiveRemoteNotification won't get called if the app has been forcibly closed.

Comment: @dperconti I will do this when I get home. I am using the fetchCompletion one. And it works fine on development but not at all in production.

Comment: do normal push notifications work in production?

Comment: @dperconti Yes regular ones work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally have come to a conclusion. It turns out in iOS 8 silent notifications do not guarantee an execution of the code in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` while using production certificates. In development it works the same as it did in iOS 7, but not in production. You can read more about this [here.](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1119690#1119690) "Apple are not acknowleding this change in background behaviour as a bug, they acknowledge the change but say its intentional." - [mungbeans](https://devforums.apple.com/people/mungbeans)

Hope this helped anyone with the same question, sorry to inform you of this news. As a result of this I needed to rebuild my whole app.

Answer (score 0):

In development, I assume you're using a development provisioning profile tied to the push certificate you've configured on Parse.

When you use TestFlight, you're required to use a Release provisioning profile. That profile would be tied to a different push certificate.  So, if you haven't configured a release push certificate (and enabled push on your app id for distribution), that is why you're not seeing pushes in TestFlight builds.

I haven't use Parse for push before, but in Urban Airship, for instance, they make it easy for you to configure a dev and release certificate for a single app.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have done this. I have a development provisioning profile linked to a development push notification certificate on parse as well as a production providing profile and production push notification linked to parse. I can receive notifications but silent ones are not executing code in didReceiveRemoteNotifcation.